# how to get the value of id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with `id` property and I would like to get the value of the `id`. Here is my work.

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {

      data: []

    }
    populate() {


      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        data.push( < ChildComponent id = {
            i
          }
          />)

        }
      }

      getValue() {

        let tmp = data[0]

        alert(tmp.id)

      }

      render() {
        {
          this.populate
        }

        return (

          <
          Button onClick = {
            this.getValue
          } > alert ID < /Button>

        )
      }

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

`populate()` inserts five childcomponent to data.

`getValue()` is where I want to alert id of the component.

`undefined` is being alerted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `props.id`.Because `id` is not property of component `tmp` itself. Its present in `props` because `id` is passed as `prop` here `data.push(<ChildComponent id={i}/>)`

```
getValue(){
   let tmp = data[0]
   alert(tmp.props.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
}
getValue(){

    alert(this.child_0.props.id)

}

render(){

   return(
    <>
        {(new Array[5]).map((item, idx) => <ChildComponent ref={e => this['child_' + idx]} key={idx} id={idx}/>)}
        <Button onClick={this.getValue}>alert ID</Button>
    </>

    )
}

}
```